# helm template to fetch a value from nested yaml doesnt work

Tags: templates, kubernetes-helm

```
crossregion:
  us:
    public:
      us-geo: s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Dallas: s3.dal.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Washington: s3.wdc.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      San Jose: s3.sjc.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
    private:
      us-geo: s3.private.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Dallas: s3.private.dal.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Washington: s3.private.wdc.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      San Jose: s3.private.sjc.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
    direct:
      us-geo: s3.direct.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Dallas: s3.direct.dal.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Washington: s3.direct.wdc.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      San Jose: s3.direct.sjc.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
  eu:
    public:
      eu-geo: s3.eu.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Amsterdam: s3.ams.eu.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Frankfurt: s3.fra.eu.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Milan: s3.mil.eu.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
    private:
      eu-geo: s3.private.eu.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Amsterdam: s3.private.ams.eu.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Frankfurt: s3.private.fra.eu.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Milan: s3.private.mil.eu.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
    direct:
      eu-geo: s3.direct.eu.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
      Amsterdam: s3.direct.ams.eu.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
```

The value I need to get is actually `crossregion.us.private.us-geo`

For above values.yaml file, I am assigning `EndPointType` based on a condition and the value will be `private or direct`
regionSubstr will be `us` in this case and hence appending `-geo` to get the final string as in `crossregion.us.private.us-geo`

`ibm.io/object-store-endpoint: "https://{{ index $secondaryValueFile.crossregion $regionSubstr.$EndPointType.$regionSubstr }}-geo"`

The above templating doesnt work though many combinations were tried.
Where am  I going wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest the template expressions here.  In particular, you need to pass an `index` invocation as a field parameter to `index`.

Breaking this down into smaller pieces:

```yaml
{{- $regionGeo := printf "%s-geo" $regionSubstr -}}
{{- $hostname := index $secondaryValueFile.crossregion $regionSubstr $EndpointType $regionGeo -}}
ibm.io/object-store-endpoint: "https://{{ $hostname }}"
```

The `-geo` suffix needs to be inside the template expression somewhere; I assign `us-geo` to another temporary variable using `printf` to compute that, and then it can go in the nested `index` expression with the various map layers above it.

It'd also be valid to inline it

```
https://{{ index $secondaryValueFile ... (printf "%s-geo" $regionSubstr) }}
```

though that's probably less readable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Above usage gives "error calling index: index of untyped nil" . Checking the issue now.

Comment: So above error was due to yaml indentation mistake. Working as expected !!!

Comment: If index is not found , helm installation error out.Is there a graceful way to handle this